# can "rosbag filter" create a new bag file with multiple topics within it?

Tags: ros, rosbag, bagfile, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a bagfile with a lot of topics in it.
For some reason I would like to filter out 4 topics of that bagfile into a new bagfile:

```
   rosbag filter old_bag.bag new_bag.bag "topic=='/stereo/left/image_rect' '/stereo/right/image_rect' '/stereo/left/camera_info'  '/stereo/right/camera_info'"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue what the correct syntax is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191003/can-%22rosbag-filter%22-create-a-new-bag-file-with-multiple-topics-within-it?/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The filter statement is just python, so you can use `or`:

```
rosbag filter old_bag.bag new_bag.bag "topic == '/stereo/left/image_rect' or topic == '/stereo/right/image_rect' or topic == '/stereo/left/camera_info' or topic == '/stereo/right/camera_info'"
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 37

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2017-06-30**:
If you want to record a whole namespace, e.g., "stereo", you can make use of Python's `in` operator:

```
rosbag filter old_bag.bag new_bag.bag "'stereo' in topic"
```